# Can step counter be used for api level less than 19 in android?

Tags: sensors, sensormanager

I've been trying to build a step counter for my own use. I tried this code,

```
Sensor countSensor = sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_STEP_COUNTER);
if (countSensor !=null
{
    sensorManager.registerListener(this,CountSensor,SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_UI);
} else {
    Toast.makeText(this,"Count Sensor not Availabe in this device !!",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

but, I did not get a positive output. It says that I have lower API than 19. How can I get things working for lower APIs?